# Vim scriptからコマンドラインにコマンドを挿入する方法を教えてください。

Tags: vim

Vim scriptからコマンドラインにコマンドを入力する方法を教えてください。

例えば、Vim scriptで
let cmd = 'echo "Hello"'
という変数があり、これをコマンドラインに挿入し、
Enterを押すと、このExコマンドを実行したいのですが、
どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
call feedkeys(':' . cmd, 'n')
```

で出来るはずです。